# Save function pointer in shared memory

Tags: c, linux

I know that data can be saved and utilized by multiple applications using shared memory .I would like to know is it possible to save the function pointer in shared memory?My purpose here is to make a call back from my shared object to functions with same return value and parameter of different applications.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pointers inside shared memory segment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10776762/pointers-inside-shared-memory-segment)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use function pointers across processes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561620/is-it-possible-to-use-function-pointers-across-processes)

Comment: @Aravind that asks about data, not function pointers.

Comment: @Marc I am not using function pointer across application instead I am using between application and shared object

Comment: You need to provide more information. "Shared memory" and "shared objects" are two *completely* different things.

Comment: Only possible in a child-copy of its parent e.g. after `fork` not followed by `exec`.

Comment: @Jonathon Reinhart Ok I am having a gsm library which access the gsm API. The GSM library is having a pthread and when ever an event occurs it should call a function in same format but in different applications.

Answer (score 3):

No.

Unless you have somehow loaded your code into the shared memory region, or otherwise caused the code to be loaded at the same address in both processes, the function pointer will not be valid.

Comment: I have access of my shared object to all the applications .But each applications are getting different instance of my .so library

Comment: Exactually - ld.so doesn't guarantee where the program/libraries will be loaded in a process. I think you should reconsider your design.

Comment: definitely I will consider your advice .I need to broadcast/multicast a data from ex.so to app1,app2 and app3. Can you suggest any better methodology for achieving that?

Comment: @Black Are you looking for equivalent of Windows RWS (Read-Write-Shared) segments? There is not equivalent on Linux, you need to use this manually. And in both Windows and Linux this will not allow storing pointers in a shared segments.

Comment: Are those the same application? If a process forks multiple children, they will all have their code loaded at the same addresses. In that case, there's no need for "shared memory" (shm_get) - you could just `mmap(MAP_SHARED)` an anonymous region and use that between all child processes.

Comment: If these are different applications that aren't children of a single parent, then you will need to avoid putting pointers in the shared memory region.

Comment: @Jonathon Reinhart Nope they all are different applications but require some or other service of GSM API

Comment: @Jonathon Reinhart the event is happening in the thread of gsmlib.so  .The   lib should inform the applications about the event and that is what I am trying to acheive. Hope u got me

Comment: That thread exists in each process that is using the library then. It is not clear why shared memory is being used here.

Comment: @Jonathon Reinhart when i registered the call back in the library from different applications ,the call back happened only to one applications.So I thought if I save every function pointer registrations in shared memory then i can make an array like structure of function pointer and in loop i can call back the functions like broadcast/multicast

Comment: Oh my god. Talk about an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are completely sure of what you are doing, It sounds a bad idea to me to save function pointers in shared memory segment, You may end up accessing a function pointer which your process doesn't have privilege of and may end up in crashing your program.

Answer (score 0):

It is not guaranteed that a shared library will be loaded to the same address for two different applications. Even worse, a library could be loaded to any random address due to address space layout randomization. Hence, a function pointer is not invariant and hence can't be stored anywhere.

As solution, you could create a function table with all possible callbacks in both processes and store offset to a function in shared memory. For sure, those tables should be *exactly* the same.

Answer (score -1):

no, cannot share the function pointer , if you want, u need to make library of that function and use it in your process